# Is that inequality obvious?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Here is the inequality:
$$ 2 \left | \sin \left ( \frac{1}{2} N^n \pi h \right ) \right | \cdot \left | \sin \left ( N^n \pi \left ( x + \frac{h}{2} \right ) \right ) \right |  \leqslant N^n \pi |h| $$
Where $N$ is natural odd number, $x, h \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $h \neq 0$. Author of my book thinks that it's obvious - for me not really. Could someone explain to me why this inequality holds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obviuous. Note that $|\sin(x)|\leq|x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ is used to estimate the first factor. Then you get 
\begin{align*}
2 \left | \sin \left ( \frac{1}{2} N^n \pi h \right ) \right |   \leqslant N^n \pi |h|. 
\end{align*}
Since $|\sin(x)|\leq1$ also holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$, the second factor can be estimated by 1.

Comment: This is indeed obvious, haha. I wasn't sure about that $|\sin x| \leq |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of smoke and mirrors around here.

Let's define $a=N^n\pi h$ and $b=N^n\pi x$. Then the inequality simplifies to
$$2\left|\sin{a\over2}\right|\cdot\left|\sin\left({a\over2}+b\right)\right|\leqslant|a|$$
which, come to think of it, is obvious indeed.